# Set key and value in multi-dimensional array object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

All i need is to add [checked]  => 1 in some of the arrays on a condition: 
i have a variable and wants to compare that with the value of 'name' . Ex: If my variable matches with Display or Forwarding, then insertion of a new key and value has to be done.

can anybody tell me how to do that ? I want to directly go to specific index like at 0 or 1 or any index of features array and want to insert new key and value like [checked] => 1

```
   Array
        (
            [Call xyz] => Array
                (
                    [features] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Display
                                    [display] => webxxx
                                    [category] => x
                                    [uniq_id] => x
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Forwarding
                                    [display] => webxxx
                                    [category] => x
                                    [uniq_id] => x
                                )
                        )
               )
           [Hidden] => Array
               (
                   [features] => Array
                      (
                         [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => XYZ
                                [display] => webxxx
                                [category] => x
                                [uniq_id] => x
                        )

                        [1] => Array
                          (
                               [name] => ABC
                               [display] => webxxx
                               [category] => x
                               [uniq_id] => x
                          )
                   )
             )
```

Comment: In the future, please include your best coding attempt in your question.  This helps us to know that you have tried to self-solve, that you'd done some research, and we may only need to make minor adjustments to your work (as opposed to writing a full snippet for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to access down to the lowest subarray where the `name` key resides.  The first level keys are `Call xyz` and `Hidden`.  The second level subarrays are both keyed with `features`.  The third level has indexed keys.  `name` is an associative key on the fourth level.

Once you work your way down to the fourth level, you can concisely write `in_array()` in your condition to check if the lowest row of data qualifies to receive the new `checkbox => 1` element.  (Alternatively, you could omit the `in_array()` call and use: `$set3["name"] == "Display" || $set3["name"] == "Forwarding"` but this is more verbose and uglier to scale up.)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3cd0b06953f68d905a0af1b1846390dcd8041b38))

```
$array = [
    "Call xyz" => [
        "features" => [
            ["name" => "Display", "display" => "webxxx", "category" => "x", "uniq_id" => "x"],
            ["name" => "Forwarding", "display" => "webxxx", "category" => "x", "uniq_id" => "x"]
        ]
    ],
    "Hidden" => [
        "features" => [
            ["name" => "XYZ", "display" => "webxxx", "category" => "x", "uniq_id" => "x"],
            ["name" => "ABC", "display" => "webxxx", "category" => "x", "uniq_id" => "x"]
        ]
    ]
];

$whitelist = ["Display", "Forwarding"];

foreach ($array as $key1 => $set1) {
    foreach ($set1 as $key2 => $set2) {
        foreach ($set2 as $key3 => $set3) {
            if (in_array($set3["name"], $whitelist)) {
                $array[$key1][$key2][$key3]["checkbox"] = 1;    
            }
        }
    }
}

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Call xyz' => 
  array (
    'features' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Display',
        'display' => 'webxxx',
        'category' => 'x',
        'uniq_id' => 'x',
        'checkbox' => 1,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Forwarding',
        'display' => 'webxxx',
        'category' => 'x',
        'uniq_id' => 'x',
        'checkbox' => 1,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'Hidden' => 
  array (
    'features' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'XYZ',
        'display' => 'webxxx',
        'category' => 'x',
        'uniq_id' => 'x',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'ABC',
        'display' => 'webxxx',
        'category' => 'x',
        'uniq_id' => 'x',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a `foreach`, check if the key/index exists on the array and check the values for "name". If that matches add [checked] => 1:

```
$index = 1;
foreach ($arrays as &$array) {
    if (array_key_exists($index, $array["features"]) &&
        ($array["features"][$index]["name"] === "Display" || $array["features"][$index]["name"] === "Forwarding")
    ) {
        $array["features"][$index]["checked"] = 1;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/v5C2r)

Answer (score -2):

This is pretty simple. Given that you know which array key `$index` you need to change :

```
$array['Call xyz']['features'][$index]['checked'] = 1;
```

Comment: wait but its not just call xyz, we have multiple arrays like this

Comment: Again, if you have that key, just replace it with a variable like i did `$index`

Comment: something like `$array[$call]['features'][$index]['checked'] = 1;`